# Pivoting string into more columns using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

My table looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['a>b>c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
"""
   col1
0  a>b>c
"""
```

and my desired output need to be like this:

```
d1 = {'col1': ['a>b>c'],'col11': ['a'],'col12': ['b'],'col13': ['c']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
print(d1)
"""    
     col1 col11 col12 col13
 0  a>b>c     a     b     c
"""
```

I have to run `.split('>')` method but then I don't know how to go on. Any help?

Comment: d1.col1.str.split('>',expand=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split using `str.split('>')`and expand the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['a>b>c'],'col2':['a>b>c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
col='col1'
#temp = df[col].str.split('>',expand=True).add_prefix(col)
temp = df[col].str.split('>',expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: col + str(int(x)+1))
temp.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer')
```

Out:

```
     col1 col11 col12 col13
 0  a>b>c     a     b     c
```

Incase if you want to do it on multiple columns you can also take

```
for col in df.columns:
    temp = df[col].str.split('>',expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: col + str(int(x)+1))
    df = temp.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer')
```

Out:

```
   col21 col22 col23 col11 col12 col13  col1   col2
0   a     b      c     a     b      c   a>b>c a>b>c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split`:

```
d = {'col1': ['a>b>c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = pd.concat([df, df.col1.str.split('>', expand=True)], axis=1)
df.columns = ['col1', 'col11', 'col12', 'col13']
df
```

Output:

```
    col1    col11   col12   col13
0   a>b>c   a        b        c
```